# how to concatenate multiple 2dim tensors vertically into one in tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am wondering how should we concatenate multiple tensors with different shapes into one tensor in keras. I tried `tf.keras.layers.concatenate` for that as follow:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tf.keras.layers import concatenate

print(tensor_1.shape)
print(tensor_2.shape)

new_tensor = concatenate([tensor_1, tensor_2],axis=1)
new_tensor
```

but I got the following value error:

```
shape of tensor_1 (?, 30, 30, 128)
shape of tensor_2 (?, 26, 26, 128)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-24-96d471a8e99e> in <module>()
----> 1 concatenate([tensor_1, tensor_2], axis=1)

4 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/layers/merge.py in build(self, input_shape)
    517             shape[axis] for shape in shape_set if shape[axis] is not None)
    518         if len(unique_dims) > 1:
--> 519           raise ValueError(err_msg)
    520 
    521   def _merge_function(self, inputs):

ValueError: A `Concatenate` layer requires inputs with matching shapes except for the concat axis. Got inputs shapes: [(None, 30, 30, 128), (None, 26, 26, 128)]
```

I think in Conv1D, concatenation is simple, in Conv2D, it is not known to me how to make concatenation. Does anyone know how to do this in keras? any idea?

**update**:

I also tried to treat each tensor as matrix and tried to concatenate them:

```
tf.concat(0, [[tensor_1], [tensor_2]])
```

but still, I ended up with a similar value error as follow:

> ValueError: Dimension 2 in both shapes must be equal, but are 30 and
> 26. Shapes are [1,?,30,30,128] and [1,?,26,26,128].   From merging shape 0 with other shapes. for '{{node concat/concat_dim}} = Pack[N=2,
> T=DT_INT32, axis=0](concat/concat_dim/0, concat/concat_dim/1)' with
> input shapes: [1,?,30,30,128], [1,?,26,26,128].

**desired output**

I am not sure how multiple tensor can be concatenated, so I am okay with output as tensor with shape of  `(W, H, C)`. How should we do this in keras? any idea?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can concatenate two tensors only when they have the same shapes but for axis along which concatenating.

```py
x = np.arange(20).reshape(2, 2, 5)
y = np.arange(20, 30).reshape(2, 1, 5)
tf.keras.layers.concatenate([x, y], axis=1)  # (2, 3, 5)
```

[tf.keras.layers.concatenate](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/concatenate)

I recommend you rethink whole network so that you don't bother about two different shape tensors. If you can't, I'd say you

1. crop

```py
x = np.arange(2*30*30*128).reshape(2, 30, 30, 128)
y = np.arange(2*26*26*128).reshape(2, 26, 26, 128)
x2 = tf.keras.layers.Cropping2D(cropping=((0, 0), (2, 2)))(x)
tf.keras.layers.concatenate([x2, y], axis=1)  # (2, 56, 26, 128)
```

[tf.keras.layers.Cropping2D](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/Cropping2D)

2. zeropad

```py
x = np.arange(2*30*30*128).reshape(2, 30, 30, 128)
y = np.arange(2*26*26*128).reshape(2, 26, 26, 128)
y = tf.keras.layers.ZeroPadding2D(padding=((0, 0), (2, 2)))(y)
tf.keras.layers.concatenate([x, y2], axis=1)  # (2, 56, 30, 128)
```

[tf.keras.layers.ZeroPadding2D](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/ZeroPadding2D)

Note: `tf.keras.layers.concatenate` and `tf.keras.layers.Conatenate`, which inherits from `tf.keras.layers.Layer` are different.

Comment: how could you concatenate those: `(?, 30, 30, 128)` with `(?, 26, 26, 128)`? let's say we could crop or filter so we could have `(?, 26, 30, 128)`, `(?, 26, 26, 128)`, how do we concatenate them correctly? how can we reshape or pad`(?, 30, 30, 128)` , `(?, 26, 26, 128)` to something we can concatenate them into one tensor? any idea?

Comment: You can't reshape because they don't have the same number of elements, batchsize * 30*30*128 !== batchsize*26*26*128. You can pad zeros to ```(?, 26, 26, 128)``` to make ```(?, 30, 30, 128)```, or you can crop ```(?, 30, 30, 128)``` into ```(?, 26, 26, 128)```. But I rather would like to say, you have to reconsider whole structure of network.

Comment: yeah, done, but I haven't throughly tested. In some papers tensors are crop/zeropad, but I'm not sure if they are reasonably correct.

Comment: How did you end up with non-matching shapes?

Comment: I don't have that situation usually. If I had to,IMHO, I would go with Conv2D, Conv2DTranspose, zero padding or Cropping.

Comment: I'm not sure what "mathematically correct" means. But if you don't go with 2**N dimension, sometimes it bothers to make a network. For example, when you make a U-Net, you will some Conv2D and some Upsampling2D. When input dimension is 256, hidden layers will be like 256, 128, 64, 129, 256. But if input 255, 255, 127, 63, 126, 252. You see input and output dimension are different, and you have to do something to match it. You wouldn't work if input dimension was chosen rightly.

Comment: @Watanabe.N I tried the above attempt for my tensor, but I have value error. Since we don't give a number of samples in those tensor `(?, 30, 30, 128) and (?, 26, 26, 128)`, how they could be cropped or zero-padded? any possible updates in your posted answer? Thanks!

Comment: @Watanabe.N [this is the error](https://gist.github.com/adamFlyn/e4a2b3c49a72b006c39ea15a90ec6452) that I got after I tried the above attempt. I don't know how should I use above attempt for tensors without batch_size `(?, 30, 30, 128) and (?, 26, 26, 128)`. I looked into documentaion, but it is not clear for me how to use for my case. Would you mind take a look error and give possible update? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228778/discussion-between-hamilton-and-watanabe-n).